# Django Email Verification

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, email, email-verification

I'm adding a feature to the social media website project that is email verification  while signing up for new users.

But I'm unable to create profile object to generate token using uuid4 class in administration page of django and also the data between the user object and profile object are not getting linked to each other

I have attached the link to the project

https://github.com/nitinjain-tech/django_email_verification

please help me out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We're not going to go off-site and dig through your code on GitHub. Please [edit] a [mre] directly into your question.